# Background color not showing up in IE 7

Tags: css

Hi i have code like.

```
div.secondHeader

{
    position: relative;
    z-index:0;
    width: 988px;
    height: 90px;
        background-color: grey; 
    /*background-image : url('images/logo_bg.gif'); */

}
```

the background color does not show up in IE 7 . While it works in IE8 . any problem with the code

Comment: try background-color: gray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pinusnegra commented, try "gray"

http://www.nutt.net/2005/10/14/grey-vs-gray-it-matters-to-internet-explorer/

If you're in a situation like this in the future, you could double-check the [Web Colors table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors).  It seems `grey` isn't in the HTML 4.01 specification, but `gray` is.

Comment: +1. 'grey' is the British English spelling. 'gray' is American English. The standards are always based on American English, so you need to use 'gray' and 'color', not 'grey' or 'colour'. Some browsers are more forgiving than others, but technically they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

Better yet, use hex color! #BBB, #CCC, #DDD, etc. When you use a shortcut like "gray", you are at the mercy of what the browser thinks "gray" should look like.

Comment: +1; Tho there are [web standards](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp).  How [standard-conformant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors) browsers are (yet) is a different story :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to overcome this problem is to use hex code for the colors.